# Nodejs https request onData event firing multiple times

Tags: node.js, https, request

I am trying to figure out why my `console.log()` statement is happening twice.  If I log to the console outside of `res.on('data) { ... }`, I only see it log one time, but, if I log to the console within the `onData` function, it fires twice.

**Question:**
Why is `res.on('data) { ... }` firing twice?

This is the code that i used and is straight from the Node documentation located at this page:

```
const https = require('https');

const options = {
  hostname: 'www.myEndpoint.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/path/to/endpoint?parameter1=true&parameter2=false',
  method: 'GET'
};

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    console.log('This console log happens twice for some reason');
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});
req.end();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "res" object is a duplex stream (important for this case is that it's reading on the "data" event) that is piped from your https request. Basically a stream is open until one endpoint is closed or null is written to a read stream endpoint.

What is happening is that the https request socket is just writing to your stream multiple times. If you're looking to capture the end of data being sent from your https request, you should create a function for the "end" event.

res.on('end', () => console.log('w/e here'));

Comment: You are the man.  I might have another question coming up for you soon if I can't figure out your advice completely.  I will accept your answer when I figure it out.  Thanks @MisterSnow!

Comment: :P Anytime. I'm on right now so I'll be able to get back to ya fairly quickly.

Comment: so... I am trying to set the result of the request in the `onData` method and then trying to `console.log()` it in the `onEnd` method. But, I think the `onEnd` method is executing before the stream is complete, so it ends up being an empty string.  Am I supposed to use promises or something here?

Comment: For that, I would have a variable outside of the res.on scopes, and just append the data to it from res.on('data'), then display the results of that variable in the res.on('end') event, as such:

    var finalData = '';

    res.on('data', (data) => {
      finalData += data.toString();
    });

    res.on('end', () => console.log(finalData))

Comment: Thanks!  It works as intended now!!  I have accepted your answer as correct on this post.